# Germanium bandgap with DFT+U calculations

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, density-functional-theory

DFT calculations with GGA functionals result in bulk germanium being metallic. Has anybody ever tried to correct this result by computing the bandgap with DFT+U in Quantum ESPRESSO?
I tried but failed. I suspect this is due to the fact that the states near the gap aren't related to the 3d shell that receives correction from the U term.

Comment: There definitely must have been work on this. https://docs.quantumatk.com/casestudies/germanium/germanium.html

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried DFT+U to fix this issue with QE. But I was struggling to reproduce its band gap. Then, it turns out that the pseudo-potential which possesses lmax=1 (excluding semi-core 3d electrons contribution) works well.
You can try this pseudo-potential Ge.pbe-kjpaw.UPF:
https://pseudopotentials.quantum-espresso.org/upf_files/Ge.pbe-kjpaw.UPF
Hopefully it is useful.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).